# How to increase jvm heap size pro-grammatically while project is on aws-lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aspose-slides

I have developed aws-lambda function, that collects pptx file sources from s3 bucket and builds a new presentation from given sources. 
But if the size of the sourec files is large, then I'm getting ERROR:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Java heap space",
  "errorType": "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.e5.void.setCapacity(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.e5.void.b(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.e5.void.write(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.case.write(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.case.write(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.boolean.write(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.goto.write(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.public.byte(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.public.case(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.public.int(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.switch.public(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.internal.eu.switch.if(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.acy.do(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.Presentation.do(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.Presentation.do(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.Presentation.do(Unknown Source)",
    "com.aspose.slides.Presentation.save(Unknown Source)",
    "com.prdxn.testing.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:60)",
    "com.prdxn.testing.demo.LambdaFunctionHandler.handleRequest(LambdaFunctionHandler.java:1)"
  ]
}
```

---

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Map<String, String[]>, String> {
    @Override
    public String handleRequest(Map<String, String[]> input, Context context) {
        // AWS S3 bucket configuration..
        String AccessKeyID = "xxx";
        String SecretAccessKey = "xxx";
        String clientRegion = "xxx";
        String bucket_name = "xxx";
        BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials(AccessKeyID, SecretAccessKey);
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(clientRegion)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds)).build();
        // Closing AWS S3 bucket configuration..

        Presentation finalPresentation = new Presentation();
        ISlideCollection finalPresentationSlides = finalPresentation.getSlides();

        String dest = "result.pptx";
        String[] keys = input.get("keys"); // get pptx file name from s3 bucket
        for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            String key_name = keys[i];
            Presentation sourcePresentation = new Presentation(
                    s3Client.getObject(bucket_name, key_name).getObjectContent());
            try {

                finalPresentationSlides.addClone(sourcePresentation.getSlides().get_Item(0));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                sourcePresentation.dispose();
            }
        }

        final StreamTransferManager manager = new StreamTransferManager(bucket_name, dest, s3Client);
        MultiPartOutputStream os = null;

        try {
            os = manager.getMultiPartOutputStreams().get(0);
            finalPresentation.save(os, SaveFormat.Pptx);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            os.close();
        }
        manager.complete();
        // Finishing of
        return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33607130/how-to-increase-java-heap-size-in-aws-lambda

Comment: I had seen the above link that requirement was different. And the above requirement is different